# wp.blocks.registerBlockType not showing what I want on the frontend

Tags: customization, shortcode, block-editor

According to my understanding, whatever is displayed in the `save:` function is what is shown on the page in the front end?
So I am trying to query the database from my block to get information I am storing there but I cannot figure out how to use the `fetch()` function in the `save:` area.

when I change the code in `save:` to this the block says it contains unexpected or invalid content, but the block still works.

```
  save: function(props) {
    return wp.element.createElement(
      "div",
      { style: { border: "3px solid " + props.attributes.color } },
      'foobar baz'
    );
  }
})
```

do I have to use props here or something?

Comment: `edit` and `save` functions don't need to be similar at all. You could have totally different HTML in each. Does this help with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: As long as you tell your attributes where to pull their data from in the saved HTML, as Alvaro noted, you can make the `save` function's output whatever you need it to be - it doesn't have to match `edit` at all. The `edit` and `save` functions' only requirements are that they return something, and that you provide a way for them to interact with the attributes. While you're editing, it's best practice to use `wp.element.createElement` rather than `React.createElement`.

Comment: ok I'll update my question, those last comments cleared up some things

Answer (score 1):

Any changes to the `save` property will cause issues with existing blocks because static blocks save the markup in `save` to the post content. If you make a change, you'll need to use the `deprecated` property to tell Gutenberg how to handle the differences between the `save` and what is in the post content. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-deprecation/) for the API.

For example:

```
registerBlockType( 'blockname', {
    //existing properties,
    deprecated: [
        {
            attributes: { // whatever your attributes were for the old version }
            save: // the old version of the save function     
         }
      ]
})
```

As for using the `fetch()` function, you should be able to use it in the function as expected before you return data but I'm not sure what the benefit would be of doing it there. What might be better, is doing it in the `edit` property and setting the data as an `attribute` of the block.

Pseudo code:

```
edit: ( props ) => {
    fetch() // not sure what we're getting here so...?
    .then(data => {
        if ( data.thing ) {
            this.setAttributes( { attName: data.thing } )
        }
    })

}

save: function(props) {
    return wp.element.createElement(
      "div",
      { style: { border: "3px solid " + props.attributes.color } },
      {props.attributes.attName}
    );
  }
})
```

Hope it helps!